# Why I can't load ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

[image]
Error: Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell it the extension since the view engine is already set up as EJS. Try changing it to `res.render('index')`. Also, your index.ejs file name has 2 periods.

Comment: Did you fix the file name and restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to set the ejs as a view engine even you don't require the ejs?